# Interview Q: Using Moq to verify an exception thrown without interfaces?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Okay, I was asked this:

*Given this class*

```
public class ModelWrapper
{
    private Customer _customer;             // Entity Framework POCO model

    public ModelWrapper(Customer model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("model");

        _customer = model;
    }
}
```

> *Write a unit test using Moq to test The ArugmentNullException is thrown when passing in a null parameter. NOTE: You do not need to
>   implement an interface*

Okay, so what I thought would work would be something like this in xUnit:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldTestArgumentNullException()
{
    var test = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(
        new ModelWrapper(null)
    );

    Assert.Equal(test.ParamName,"model");
}
```

And even though this works, it wasn't the correct answer. I then tried this:

```
_mock.Setup( w => new ModelWrapper(null)).Throws(new ArgumentNullException("model"));
_mock.Verify();
```

That DIDN'T work, and I got this exception instead:

> Message: System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a method invocation: w=> new ModelWrapper(null)

So then, what IS the correct answer?

EDIT UPDATE: I was told that I can use just a concrete class in Moq, something like this:

```
 var _mock = new Mock<ModelWrapper>();
```

But, I'm still failing to see how that can be done. As you see as I wrote the code using the concrete class ModelWrapper, it still failed.

Comment: Might be better to ask the question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't see how Moq could be used here. It's straightforward. Call `new ModelWrapper(null);` and make sure an exception was thrown through the appropriate testing framework (MSTest/xUnit/whatever).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot possibly read your potential future employers mind. Technically, Moq is not necessary to write a perfectly correct unit test.

Comment: I was told that I is possible, but I don't see how. They did say that I can use a concrete class such as: var mock = new Mock<ModelWrapper>();

Comment: I would say that the employer explicitly requested you use Moq and you did not, and that is why they marked your original answer incorrect.

Comment: Well, yeah,I first stated that I could not see how Moq could be used and then proceeded with my xUnit demo; When I was told it wasn't the answer they were expecting, I then tried my code using Moq, and it failed anyways. So what's the difference? Obviously, they had SOMETHING in mind and there had to be a trick that I'm not aware of in Moq

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfectly good test using only what Visual Studio gives us:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void ModelWrapperThrowsOnNullModel() 
{
    new ModelWrapper(null);
}
```

You can now add all kinds of third party libraries, but guessing what your potential future employer may have wanted to see is beyond the scope of technical expertise. There is no reason to mock anything, so the need to use Moq (or similar libraries) for this task is an artificial requirement that only exists in the head of the interviewer.

Comment: Which is exactly what I was thinking as well, and since xUnit does something in a similar fashion and this is an exercise in futility. I thought that was the answer using xUnit since I can get away with a couple of lines of code, but it wasn't. The interviewer gave kudos for doing something like this in xUnit, seeing that other candidates couldn't even come up with something like I did! Not only did I come up with a unit test to test the exception, I also tested the parameter name (see the constructor, it throws the ParamName as "model")

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the use of Moq here is totally unnecessary and side with nvoigt's answer.

That said, given that they want you to use moq it can still be done, which seems more like a hack to me.

```
[TestClass]
public class MoqVerifyExceptionWithoutInterface {
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void ModelWrapperThrowsOnNullModel() {
        var mock = new Mock<ModelWrapper>(MockBehavior.Strict, null);
        try {
            var model = mock.Object;
        } catch (TargetInvocationException e) {
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                throw e.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }

    public class ModelWrapper {
        private Customer _customer;
        public ModelWrapper(Customer model) {
            if (model == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
            _customer = model;
        }
    }

    public class Customer { }
}
```